# How to work out this probability (100 people, 2/3 chance of being correct, 55-45 split)

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to work out the answer to this Q, and i'm stuck.

Assume that we have 100 voters and each voter has a two-thirds chance choosing correctly between binary options. We are conducting a binary vote between A and B. Further suppose that the difference in votes between the two positions is a 5% split: 55 voters choose A and 45 choose B. The voters are both independent and sincere.

How confident should we be, based on this distribution, that option A is correct?

Comment: My Bayes-sense is tingling! Start by thinking: Assuming that option A is correct, what is the probability that 55 voters choose A and 45 voters choose B?

Comment: @MattiP. That's relatively low, just because there are so many possible outcomes. One usually says "What is the probability that _at least_ 55 voters choose A" (or possibly "at most", depending on what you're after) instead.

Comment: Are the voters making independent choices?

Comment: Yes! sorry, I should have included that

Comment: We don't have enough information. Even if voters are independent, this doesn't imply that given A is the right choice, the probabilities of their answers are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

If the voters are independent, given that $A$ is correct the chance of getting this vote is ${100 \choose 55}\frac {2^{55}}{3^{100}}$.  Given that $B$ is correct the chance of getting this vote is ${100 \choose 45}\frac {2^{45}}{3^{100}}$.  This gives the chance $A$ is correct as $\frac {1024}{1025}$ as the binomials are equal.  If the voters are not independent we need to know about the correlations to be able to say anything.